# unable to log from inside of a pod framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, cocoapods, nslog

I have created a `iOS` & `tvOS` framework and i am using `cocoapods` to distribute it to all my projects. I am having difficulties when trying to do a `NSLog` from inside the classes of the framework.

The framework is really simple, it is composed of several classes and has two dependencies (`AFNetworking` & `JSONModel`), other then that i am not doing anything special.

Is there something i an missing or doing wrong?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7277804/ios-iphone-ipad-ipodtouch-view-real-time-console-log-terminal

Comment: @AnnaBillstrom the problem is not that the console is not visible, it is, but the logs that comes from the framework aren't appearing in it. if i log outside of the framework (in the project) it is logging

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just needed to Clean my build folder and rebuild to have the updated pod code run and the log statements to show up.

I got this idea from here: [Editing locked files from a CocoaPods framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34915886/editing-locked-files-from-a-cocoapods-framework/34916055#comment96184620_53372020)