# How to enable SocketRocket logging

Tags: ios, swift, websocket, socketrocket

**Given**

- iOS project written in Swift
- Uses Facebook's SocketRocket in order to connect websocket: https://github.com/facebook/SocketRocket
- SocketRocket was installed using CocoaPods

**Question**

How to enable logging of SocketRocket?

**PS**

Using debugger I can see that `SRFastLog(@"Connected");` method was called. But nothing is printed in the console

Answer (score 2):

You can enable log using uncomment `SR_DEBUG_LOG_ENABLED` preprocessor macro.

See line #15 in [SRLog.h](https://github.com/facebook/SocketRocket/blob/41b57bb2fc292a814f758441a05243eb38457027/SocketRocket/Internal/Utilities/SRLog.h) file.

NOTE : You can not change dependency source file directly. You have to use either add sub module in your project or you have to fork that particular repo.

Ref : [Editing locked files from a CocoaPods framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34915886/editing-locked-files-from-a-cocoapods-framework)